# Hot fix bugs(Patching) in a release for iOS/Android (Including compiled script changes) in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, patch, auto-update

I need to find a solution for hot patching the game builds after their release, so the users don't have to reinstall the whole .apk/.IPA on their devices and yet the patch is applied if their is a new build on remote server. Hence only the updated **scripts** and assets are patched and not the whole build re-downloaded and reinstalled.

So I have been looking around for a while on "Post Release Build Pipelines", "Automatic Patching Mechanisms", "Hot Fix/Patch" etc. I came across some assets on asset store:

**1. [P.A.T.C.H. - Ultimate Patching System [FULL]](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/p-a-t-c-h-ultimate-patching-system-full-46639)**

**2. [Coffee Auto Patcher System](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/coffee-auto-patcher-system-79819)**

**3. [Final Patch - Hot Update Pro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/final-patch-hot-update-pro-140852)**

**The problem exists with all these:**

1. They are either not supported for iOS/Android or;
2. They only patch asset changes using asset bundles, and do not patch compiled **scripts**.

**I came across two suggested solutions which i have no clue if it will work or not:**

1. Runtime script interpretation by using compiled scripts as text assets inside asset bundles (Since they donot support script changes) and use something like [MoonSharp](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/moonsharp-33776) to compile runtime.
2. Using custom asset packages with updated scripts to be imported in the game.

I am open to any solutions, assets/plugins/tools suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Loading other resources than compiled code is possible by using the methods of the AssetBundle class: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html

Now to the possibilities of patching code on mobile devices:

On iOS runtime recompilation, native code alteration or code emission (e.g. Reflection.Emit) is forbidden, in fact the kernel does not allow this. So trying to use things like C#'s compiler-as-a-service feature will not work. This is probably the reason why P.A.T.C.H. is not supported on mobile platforms.

Using an intepreter (like Moonsharp) on the other hand is possible but there will be a few hard nuts to crack:

- Executing an Interpreter on the main thread in Unity will heavily slow it down. I myself have done a couple of performance tests and MoonSharp is atleast 100 times slower than native calls in IL2CPP and produces a decent amout of garbadge that the gc will have to clean every now and then. This might be still ok if you are not planning on making a highspeed FPS and make the most important logic native. You will have to choose what logic that is or how to parallelize your script execution though.
- The more power you are giving to scripts by exposing internal types, the bigger the security risks will get. Especially regarding I/O. Are you sure you want to take the responsibility for someone hijacking the lua interpreter in your App?
- The conflict of trying to speed up your scripts by using multiple cores and Unity being non-thread-safe might also be one of those things. An action queue or the disruptor pattern (https://github.com/disruptor-net/Disruptor-net) can help you out with forwaring commands to the main thread.
- More stuff that I can't think of right now but that is definitely there.

In my opinion the topics you will have to deal with might get very intense and/or frustrating but it is entirely possible to do this. If you want to learn a few things on the way and have no pressure it might be an acceptable choice. If you need to be productive I highly advise you to not use an interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is very helpful.
I understand it's challenging on iOS and so far the methods we have come across have some cons, some are poor on performance and some on security. I believe it's possible to achieve it since i have seen some working products that implement that.

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution to you to implement a system that downloads everything that is not code after the app is installed? You would still have to update the apk every Patch if you make changes to the code but I guess it would end up being rather small as it contains only scripts and no other resources?

Comment: That is kind of an escape plan- a temporary solution that i also thought of going with, until i can find a proper solution. 
Thanks though.